# Protractor get seleniumAddress from config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

How can I get seleniumAddress from config?

I want to get the seleniumAddress value inside the afterLaunch.

This example is not working could you help me to fix it?

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['todo-spec.js']
    afterLaunch: function (exitCode, seleniumAddress) {
        return console.log(seleniumAddress);
    }

};
```

**Case 1:** If I will run this command

```
protractor conf.js
```

I should get

"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"

**Case 2:** If I will run this command

```
protractor conf.js --seleniumAddress 'http://example:4444/wd/hub'
```

I should get

"http://example:4444/wd/hub"

Comment: Please describe your problem or what do you want clearly? FYI: protractor gives priority to command line value of seleniumAddress if you pass it while running

Comment: I`ve just edited the question. My english is not really good. My first problem is that I want to get the seleniumAddress value inside afterLaunch method. My second problem is that if I edited the seleniumAddress using the command line I will get the correct value.

Comment: may i know the use case of printing selenium address in afterLaunch()?

Comment: I am running the protractor tests using different selenium address. Using the afterLaunch function I notify thought slack if the test are failing or not. I don't want printing the selenium address I want to know which is the seleniumAddress value to send a right notification.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts check this link to know the behavior of afterLaunch()

Comment: Solution to edit seleniumAddress is - run below command:  

protractor --seleniumAddress='http://example:4444/wd/hub' conf.js

Comment: protractor --seleniumAddress='example:4444/wd/hub' conf.js

Comment: Yes, Suresh. I am changing the seleniumAddress without any problem. The problem is that I need to get the seleniumAddress value inside the afterLaunch.

Comment: afterLaunch will be called after all tests execution completed and driver shutdown. i think here selenium address will not be available. Better try in onComplete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127368/discussion-between-adolfo-luzardo-cabrera-and-suresh-salloju).

Comment: @AdolfoLuzardoCabrera Did you get an answer on this? I was looking for the exact same thing, as I use that info to know if I'm running the tests locally or in Saucelabs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `browser.getProcessedConfig()` function as follows:

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){
    console.log(config.seleniumAddress);
});
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42418510/3211332