# How to read parameter's value, present in conf.js file of protractor in specs

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Ex: conf.js

```
exports.config = {

    directConnect: false,

    // multiCapabilities: [{
    //     browserName: 'firefox'
    // }, {
    //     browserName: 'chrome'
    // }, {
    //     browserName: 'internet explorer'
    // }],


    specs: ['Specs/spec.js'],

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

}
```

Specs:

```
 it('should be able to select the required organization', function() {

            Select_Organization.selectOrganization();

            //console.log(browser.seleniumAddress);
//This is where I need to read the config paramater values, but above is printing undefined.

            expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('p3 by NextGen - CSR & Development Capital Management Platform');
     });
```

I need to read the parameter's value present in the conf.js file, so that I can read them in specs.js file to take necessary actions based on the parameter;'s value passed in the conf.js. Is there a way in which this can be possible.

Comment: What value are you trying to read? .. your conf.js doesnt contain any values defined

Comment: I want to read parameter's value, ex value of seleniumAddress, which is http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

Comment: Yeah, got it .... pls check below ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access all the config values using `browser.getProcessedConfig`.Check [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig) for more details

An example below

```
describe('test', function(){
    it('test', function(){
        browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/registeration/#/login');
        browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){
            console.log(config.baseUrl) // Print Url
            console.log(config.specs) // Prints specs
            console.log(config.capabilities) // Prints capabilities
        })
        browser.sleep(10000)
    });
});
```

In case you are looking to make it re-usable

```
 this.getConfParameterValue = function() {
     return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
           return config.directConnect;
     }) 
 }
```

Comment: FunctionLibrary.js  this.getConfParameterValue = function() {

        browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {

           return config.directConnect; //if I print it then its fine but I am not able to return anything inside this block, its appearing as undefined. IS there any way to return things from here
        })
    }

Comment: I have udpated the answer with what you are looking for ... You have the method definition correct .. you just need to return the value

Comment: Hey on calling getConfParameterValue function, it returns a promise.I want to return the value of the config parameter