# How can I read the capabilities(browsername) from Config.js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I want to read which browser is used in config file, based on that i need to do some actions on the browser, is that possible?
I want to get the browserName from config file in someTest.js file.

```js
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

    specs: [
      '../endtoendtests/demo.js',
      '../endtoendtests/someTest.js'
      
    ],

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

   

    framework: 'jasmine',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize(); // maximize the browser before executing the feature files

    }
};
```

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872955/get-the-current-browser-name-in-protractor-test

Comment: This was answered in lot of other questions .. Reading capabilities from Spec files - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414538/how-to-read-parameters-value-present-in-conf-js-file-of-protractor-in-specs/42418510#42418510

Comment: @KishanPatel Thank you..it is worked for me..

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. Thanks all

Comment: @Basil : Great :-)

Answer (score -1):

To get the name of a browser is a easy task, but the problem is that the name is same for many browsers.

Let me explain:

There is property in window object called [Navigator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp) .

Hence you can use it like `navigator.userAgent` and for chrome it will return the browser name as

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36

Now you see the problem.

There is also property called `navigator.appName` but Strange enough,

> "Netscape"

is the application name for both IE11, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

So my advice is don`t do browser detection , always do **Feature detection**.